# Having trouble getting git to commit after setting origin

Tags: git

I'm trying to get a handle on using git. I've been using it on my PC running Kubuntu. I installed git flow and everything works like a champ.

Now, however, I need to start using a repo on my server. So, I SSH'ed into the box and created a directory for my repos and one inside of it for this particular repo. Then I moved into the directory and ran:

```
git init --shared --bare
```

Then I went to the directory of my app and did the following:

```
git remote add origin 192.168.1.5:/home/will/Repo/testgit
git push origin master
```

I tried creating another directory elsewhere on my system and then running:

```
git clone 192.168.1.5:/home/will/Repo/testgit
```

However, nothing was in the directory. I also tried going back to my original directory, doing:

```
git commit
git push origin master
```

It said there were no changes. How do I fix this?

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stage your files before committing them.

```
git add <path to your files>
```

Also you should set the files that git should ignore by making a .gitignore file in the root folder which contains the patterns of what to ignore.

Comment: Hmm. That got them staged so I could do a git commit, yet when I do a git push origin master, it says everything is up to date. When I try pulling down from there using git clone though, nothing shows up.

Comment: You do the push from the place where you committed. You don't clone, you pull the changes from the server after you cloned.

Comment: take a look at the first chapter of the progit.org/book

Comment: I went to the root of the site I'm trying to push up and did
git push origin master
but it still thinks nothing has changed.

I ran gitk. It shows a develop branch and a master branch. All the stuff I added is in develop. If I'm reading this right, wouldn't I need to do git merge develop? I tried it, and it says it is already up to date as well.

Comment: Doh! I feel so daft now. I was checking in master, not develop. So now I need to review the text and remember how to merge develop back into the master branch and I'm all set. Thanks for all the help.